# using in a while loop and then execute a for loop once cin is true

Tags: c++, loops

```
int main()
{
    int in;
    cout << "please enter a number between 1 and 70" << endl;
    cin >> in;
    string star = "*";
    const int lessthan = in < 1;
    const int greaterthan = in > 70;
    while (true) {
        if  (lessthan || greaterthan) {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cout << "please enter a number between 1 and 70" << endl;
        }
        else {
            for (int looptimes = 0; looptimes <=in ; ++looptimes ) {
                cout.width(looptimes);
                cout << star << endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

basically I just want to figure out how to end the loop from when the input is correct. Also I want to be able to stop asking once the input is correct.

Comment: Wow, that's some ugly indentation.

Comment: out of curiosity - why `star` is a `string` not a `char`, `lessthan` and `greaterthan` are `const int`s instead of `const bool`s?

Comment: Tan's style code... I refuse to read.

Comment: I copied what I needed and pasted it over without all the comments in it, so yeah indentation would be way off. For the curious person, I was trying anything I could find from google to see what would work. And yes I did try     const bools too. But it still didn't give me what I wanted.

Comment: Well, you're not going to help things by making the results of the input edit checking a `const` value. Once that's set, you're committed to the results of that edit checking, now and in perpetuity.

Answer (score 0):

Before you jump into the logic, let's talk about the coding style and usage of variables. You simply do not need most of them.

> basically I just want to figure out how to end the loop from when the input is correct

Judging from your code, I assume that the *correct* intput consists of an integer which is in range of `1 >= x >= 70`. That is a solid **statement** that can be used as a `while()` loop condition.

```
int some_number = 0;
do{
    std::cout << "Please enter a number between 1 and 70: ";
    std::cin >> some_number;
while(some_number < 1 && some_number > 70);
```

In this (much simpler) snippet of code you can see that we are asking for an input for as long as the inputted number is a valid integer **and** is out of the desired range.

If you are expecting that a user may input something else than an integer (for example, instead of `232` a user may input `some text`) you might want to use a different solution.

```
std::string line;
int some_number = 0;
do{
    std::cout << "Please enter a number between 1 and 70: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, line);
    try{
        some_number = std::stoi(line);
    } catch (...){
        some_number = 0;
    }
} while(some_number < 1 && some_number > 70);
```

This will keep asking for an integer in the desired range, even if a user inputs something invalid (here - something else than a number). We simple scan the input and put it into an `std::string`. Then we parse that string into an `int`. If we succeed, the return value is assigned to our variable. If we do not, (in case of invalid input) an exception is thrown and caught which sets `some_number` to `0`, making our `do-while` loop execute once again.

Comment: I don't mean to disregard any of this. But I've tried this already and if you include the for loop inside of this while loop, the while loop doesn't do what it's supposed to, so I guess I can narrow this down to the inner for loop being my problem since it seems that the outer while loop will only go so far in doing what it can. Thanks for the help, I appreciate my code being looked over with feedback like yours.

Comment: @rolaandoes This answer explains how to handle the problem of incorrect input by asking for it for as long as the previous one was incorrect. If you are experiencing another difficulty, please specify. I assume that you want to execute some code after you receive a correct input. What is your `for` loop supposed to do with the correct input? I would guess that you want to print some kind of a pattern, however I have spotted a `break` statement at the end of your loop body. Try removing that and see if it works

Comment: I want it to consecutively ask when the input is wrong, so I want the loop to wait for input after asking and once the input is correct run the for loop with the pattern, then stop the pattern after its first print.

Comment: I don't quite understand the "*then stop the pattern after its first print*" part. What's wrong with simply writing `for (int looptimes = 0; looptimes <=in ; ++looptimes ) { cout.width(looptimes); cout << star << endl; }` afer the `do-while` loop? Why you want to nest those loops? By the way - I think you may have a wrong idea of what `break` does. It exits the current loop, which in your example is the `for` loop, not your `while` loop